# Allocating a range to an array in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Really new and self taught so would appreciate any help

Have allocated a range from a spreadsheet to an array but it starts the data in row 1 of the array.

```
Dim arr As Variant
arr = Range("DATA")
```

Is there any way of starting in row 0?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You would have to loop through each cell and assign the value to the item of an array. Whenever you assign a range directly to a variable, the array will start from item 1.

Comment: no, please no luke_t. Range -> array is very slow, and you are doing it in a loop

Comment: While this is possible (and @Pierre 's answer shows the efficient way to do so) -- why bother? Excel VBA code needs to regularly interact with ranges, so it is best to try to match your coding style to how the VBA object model works. Experienced VBA programmers will often write functions/subs which are designed to work with arrays using the `LBound` and `Ubound` functions to get loop bounds for processing the arrays, rather than insisting that all arrays fed to the function/sub are either 0-based or 1-based. It is best to write code which is base-agnostic.

Comment: Indeed @JohnColeman . The best is still to accept how VBA works. :-)

Comment: Thank you - I'm using another array which is using the 0base so trying to align both to be the same. Completely understand what you mean though.

Answer (score 2):

Range operations are slow, the best is to use a temporary array , and then make a copy to another array while changing the start position.
Indeed array -> array = very fast

```
Dim arr, arr2 As Variant
arr2 = Range("DATA").value2
redim arr(0 to ubound(arr2)-1, 0 to ubound(arr2,2)-1)
for i= 0 to ubound(arr2)-1
for j= 0 to  ubound(arr2,2)-1
arr(i,j)= arr2(i+1,j+1)
next
next
```

Comment: Thank you _ I have a lot to learn. Sure there is a better way to achieve the results I am getting but just starting out. Appreciate the response and your time

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are going to clean-up range-derived VBA arrays, why not make them 1-dimensional instead of falsely 2-dimensional in the case that you are dealing with a column range or a row range? The following does that as a default and also uses 0-based as a default, but provides ways to override both defaults:

```
Function RangeToArray(R As Range, Optional b As Long = 0, Optional collapse As Boolean = True) As Variant
    'returns a b-based array of the values in R
    'if the Range is 1-dimensional and collapse is true, the array returned is 1-dimensional
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, m As Long, n As Long, k As Long
    Dim vals As Variant, arr As Variant

    m = R.Rows.Count
    n = R.Columns.Count
    If m = 1 And n = 1 Then 'to catch an edge-case
        ReDim vals(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        vals(1, 1) = R.Value
    Else
        vals = R.Value
    End If
    If collapse And (m = 1 Or n = 1) Then
        k = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(m, n)
        ReDim arr(b To b + k - 1)
        For i = 1 To k
            If m = 1 Then
                arr(b + i - 1) = vals(1, i)
            Else
                arr(b + i - 1) = vals(i, 1)
            End If
        Next i
    Else
        ReDim arr(b To b + m - 1, b To b + n - 1)
        For i = 1 To m
            For j = 1 To n
                arr(b + i - 1, b + j - 1) = vals(i, j)
            Next j
        Next i
    End If
    RangeToArray = arr
End Function
```

It would be used like `A = RangeToArray(Range("A1:B3"))`

Comment: @Pierre Good observation. I added code to guard against it. Thanks.